# Will this cause a memory leak in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, pointers

In an attempt to get just a filename:

```
procedure TSomeClass.GetFileName(AData : string) : string;
var
  p : pchar;
begin

  p := pchar(AData);
  while not (p^ in ['/', '&', '#', ':']) do
    inc(p);

  result := p;

end;
```

Comment: Why do you use pointers you can easily loop using for i:=1 to length(aData)...anyway if those characters are not in the string you probably get an infinite loop witch will cause an access violation in a certain point...don't complicate yourself

Comment: Whats wrong with `SysUtils.ExtractFileName`?

Comment: @ain `SysUtils.ExtractFileName` is a fine routine but it does something different from this code

Comment: @David The OP starts his post with "In an attempt to get just a filename" - thats exactly what the `ExtractFileName` does. The name he uses for his routine (`GetFileName`) also suggest that `ExtractFileName` is what he is after. My bet is that his current implementation is just wrong, ie doesn't do what he actually wants and there is no point to replicates the logic of his code.

Comment: @ain: The possible file name is passed in a URI format e.g. file:///c:\somepath\whereisit\thefile.ext or file:///\\machine\somepath\whereisit\thefile.ext. ExtractFileName uses a LastDelimeter detection approach and wont work. Good thinking - always use whats there. My apologies for the semantic confusion.

Comment: Just to focus everyone - the issue is the pointer moving along an array and if p, after the increments, does not point to the start of the array (pchar) will the Delphi memory manager cope. The reason for the approach is speed and simplicity.

Comment: @MX4399 There is probably something for this already available too. Ie the last Delphi versions ship with Indy which sure must have URI parsing routines. Or you could use `Wininet.InternetCrackUrl` API.

Comment: @MX no need for focus. I think the question is answered. The pointer approach doesn't leak. I don't think it's really any faster and it's not simpler.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no memory leak there.  Your pointer `p` points to a block of memory that is **owned** by the string `AData` and so you do not need to free `p`.  The string class manages all allocation and deallocation for you.

What can happen though is that if the string does not contain at least one of those 4 characters your loop will run off the end and eventually raise an access violation.  You should consider terminating the loop when it reaches a null terminator.

It's just simpler to avoid pointers altogether:

```
function TSomeClass.GetFileName(const AData: string): string;
var
  i, len: Integer;
begin
  len := Length(AData);
  for i := 1 to len do
    if AData[i] in ['/', '&', '#', ':'] then begin
      Result := Copy(AData, i, len);
      exit;
    end;
  Result := '';
end;
```

The replicates the logic of your code, and removes the risk of access violations. However, your code was returning the portion of the string starting from, and including, the first instance of `/`, `&`, `#` or `:`. Is that really what you wanted?

Comment: You may be surprised, but you will have no access violation for empty string. There is a difference between `P:= PChar(S)` and `P:= Pointer(S)`. Only in the second case you get AV for empty `S`, in the first case you get a valid pointer to `#0` char

Comment: @Serg Ah you are right. I was aware of that, just forgot it! It points to a block of read only memory containing zeros.

Comment: @Rudy One zero is not enough. There certainly need to be at least two for `PWideChar(MyString)`. I have a feeling that there may even be four.

Comment: @MX4399 adding #0 to the set would solve that since a string is guaranteed to be null terminated. But not using pointers at all for this is best.

Comment: @David: you beat me to it. <g>